# Similar syntax but one shows error but another does not

Tags: c, operator-precedence

Hiii all

I made this program today

```
int main()
{
   int a = 1,2; /* Shows error */
   int b = (1,2); /* No error */
}
```

Why first one shows error while second one does not? Just ( ) makes one program compile. Why?

--Shruti

Answer (score 9):

`int a = 1,2;` `2` is treated as a variable name which cannot start with a number, hence the error.

`int b = (1,2);` [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) evaluates the operands from left to right and returns the last expression in the list i.e. `2`

Answer (score 6):

Inside the parentheses, the language specifies an expression will occur.  In that case (`b`), the comma represents the comma operator from C.

Without parentheses, the language specifies that variable declarations are separated by commas.  In the example of `a`, the compiler (parser) is expecting additional variable declarations.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is in your first statement `int a = 1,2;` the comma is not parsed to be a sequence operator.  It is part of a declaration list and attempts to instantiate an integer variable named `2` which is not allowed by the language.

The parentheses in the second statement `int b = (1,2);` force the comma to be parsed as a sequence operator.

Answer (score 0):

`(1,2)` evaluates to the last expression in the list, i.e. `2`.

Another example: `(a,b,c)` would evaluate to `c`.

In case you want to use a fractional number, use a float/double type and use the dot as a decimal symbol: `double d = 1.2;`

Answer (score 0):

None of them made sense to me at fist.

But then i remembered multiple operations in for loops. Eg:

```
for (a=1,b=2; a<1; a++)
```

Knowing that **1** is a valid expression, and that expressions are valid language elemnts, my conclusion is that **(1,2)** evaluates 1 (but does nothing with it), then evaluates 2 and returns 2.

And finally:

```
b = (1,2);
```

What does is evaluate 1 and 2 as before, return 2, and assign it to b.